# How to mock dynamodbmapper scan

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito, amazon-dynamodb

I have following code that I am trying to mock:

```
public void getOrders(Response response){
    logger.log("Getting all orders");

    DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
            .withProjectionExpression("OrderId");

    PaginatedScanList<Orders> orders = dynamoDBMapper.scan(Orders.class, scanExpression);

    response.setData(orders..stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

And the way I am trying to mock is:

```
Mockito.when(mockDynamoDBMapper.scan(Orders.class, 
             Mockito.any())).thenReturn(mockPaginatedList);
```

And I am getting following exception:

> This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
>       //incorrect:
>       someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String"); When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers. For example:
>       //correct:
>       someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
>       For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.

how should I mock `dbmapper.scan` method with any `DynamoDBScanExpression` object?

Answer (score 3):

The error has clear answer to your question. What you want is:

```
Mockito.when(mockDynamoDBMapper.scan(eq(Orders.class), 
             Mockito.any())).thenReturn(mockPaginatedList);
```

The matcher must be provided with matchers - eq(Orders.class), instead of raw values - Orders.class

Answer (score 0):

In general, what I do is first mock the PaginatedScanList which is the type of response that the mapper.scan () gives us and then I assign that response mock to the mock that it creates of the mapper when the scan () is called

```
    // here I define the values ​​that will be assigned to the filter
    Map <String, AttributeValue> expressionAttributeValues ​​= new HashMap <> ();
    expressionAttributeValues.put (": attributeValue", new AttributeValue (). withS ("value"));
    // the definition of the epxpression for the scan
    DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression ();
    scanExpression.setLimit (1); // amount of data to return
    scanExpression.setFilterExpression (("email =: attributeValue")); // the attribute to filter by
    scanExpression.setProjectionExpression ("id"); // the data to return from the row or json
    scanExpression.setExpressionAttributeValues ​​(expressionAttributeValues); // place the value by which to filter

    DynamoDBMapper mapper = mock (DynamoDBMapper.class); // The mock was created for the mapper, which is the one with different methods such as query, scan, etc.
    PaginatedScanList scanResultPage = mock (PaginatedScanList.class); // definition of the mock for the scan result

    when (scanResultPage.size ()). then (invocation -> 3); // what to return when the PaginatedScanList is called

    when (mapper.scan (Person.class, scanExpression)). then (invocation -> scanResultPage); // here returns our mocked PaginatedScanList for the scan function
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would be nice…

Comment: And the code is hard to read because of bad formatting.

Comment: add more details and code, please check and rate again